# How to Select Multiple Values from Database in php

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

How to solve 
if i select one Value form dropdown. Biside I have another drop down and its values should be auto Updated According to Option I have selected from first dropdown ?

Comment: Have you written some code or expecting some one will write for you

Comment: What are you trying to explain, be more specific

Comment: make an ajax call based on the first selected option to get the data for the other select.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dependent Dropdowns (Linked Selects) with single class (no other selectors)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870579/dependent-dropdowns-linked-selects-with-single-class-no-other-selectors)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to generate a lookup table whenever you create a drop-down list:

```
 function createDropdown(&$ddlLookup) {
 echo '<select multiple name="items[]">';
    try {
        $items = mysql_query("SELECT item_id,item_type FROM items");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($items)) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['item_type'].'"';
            echo '>'. $row['item_type'] . '</option>'."\n";
            $ddlLookup[$item_type] = $item_id;
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'No results';
    }
 echo '</select>';
 }
```

Then whenever you need the id for a given description you use that table(array) to get it:

```
   $mainDropdownLUT = array();
   createDropdown($mainDropdownLUT);

var_dump($mainDropdownLUT['testCow']);
 -> 734
```

Also, if you need to pass it to another page it can be serialized and added to a hidden field.

```
 $mainDropdownLUT = serialize($mainDropdownLUT);
 "<input type="hidden" value =\"$mainDropdownLUT\">"
 -------------------------**OTHER PAGE **--------------
  $mainDropdownLUT = unserialize($mainDropdownLUT);
```